# See you in the morning

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

"See you in the morning. Make sure you're not late," my grandfather said. Then, he handed me this photo and left. I was worried I wouldn't be able to solve my grandfather's puzzle, so I immediately set my attention to it. Late into the evening, I was struggling still and thought I would need to call him and sheepishly ask for an explanation.

Then, I had a simple idea. I grabbed a World Book Encyclopedia and set to work. Just a minute later and I knew exactly what time to meet my grandfather.

What time was I supposed to meet him?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hoping that this 'simple idea' is not *too* simple... You need to meet him at:

> **SIX AM (6am)**

Why?

> Interpret the hands of each clock using [flag semaphore code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_semaphore). The positions of each pair of hands translate in sequence to **S - I - X**.
>
>  Use the initials of the locations beneath them (**AMM**) purely to clarify that the meeting time is *ante meridiem (am)* i.e. in the *morning* (as per the title) rather than the evening...

Comment: Correct! I suppose it was "too" simple. I had some ideas for more layering, but decided to leave it at this..

Comment: @DanielC Not necessarily - at first I debated whether the numbers meant anything ciphery... To solve it I had to discard information and work out what was really important. Still puzzleworthy, just a quick one in the end :)